# How to query in GraphQL with Sequelize a many to many association? Receiving null error

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, graphql, apollo

I have many to many association, models are Decks and Tag.  I am able to console.log a JSON string with both objects, but I am unsure how to set my schema and resolver to return both in one query together, and currently receiving null.  I'm using GraphQL with Sequelize on an Apollo server, with PostgreSQL as the db.  What's the proper method to query this relationship in GraphQL, I presume I am not returning the data properly for GraphQL to read it?

Models

```
        Deck.belongsToMany(models.Tag, {
          through: models.DeckTag,
          onDelete: "CASCADE"
        });
      Tag.associate = models => {
        Tag.belongsToMany(models.Deck, {
          through: models.DeckTag,
          onDelete: "CASCADE"
        });
```

Schema for Decks

```
    export default gql`
      extend type Query {
        decks(cursor: String, limit: Int): DeckConnection!
        deck(id: ID, deckname: String): Deck!
        decksWithTags: [Deck!]!
      }

      extend type Mutation {
        createDeck(deckname: String!, description: String!): Deck!
        deleteDeck(id: ID!): Boolean!
      }

      type DeckConnection {
        edges: [Deck!]!
        pageInfo: DeckPageInfo!
      }

      type DeckPageInfo {
        hasNextPage: Boolean!
        endCursor: String!
      }

      type Deck {
        id: ID!
        description: String!
        createdAt: Date!
        user: User!
        cards: [Card!]
      }
    `;
```

Resolver in question

```
        decksWithTags: async (parent, args, { models }) => {
          return await models.Deck.findAll({
            include: [models.Tag]
          }).then(tags => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(tags));  //able to console.log correctly
          });
        },
```

Shortened sample Console.logged JSON String

```
        [
          {
            "id":1,
            "deckname":"50 words in Chinese",
            "description":"Prepare for your immigration interview",
            ***
            "userId":1,
            "tags":[
                {
                  "id":1,
                  "tagname":"Chinese",
                  ***
                  "decktag":{
                      ***
                      "deckId":1,
                      "tagId":1
                  }
                },
                {
                  "id":2,
                  ***
          {
            "id":2,
     "deckname":"English",
     ***
```

I expect to get a result in GraphQL playground that looks similar to the JSON string.